# Extend with defaults if property not exists

Tags: jquery

I have an object

```
myObject = {
    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '12',
    color : '000000'
}
```

And Default Options

```
myDefaults = {
    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '15',
    color : 'FF0000',
    weight : 'bold',
    decoration : 'underline'
}
```

And now I want to merge them with `jQuery.extend()`.

My merging rule is : If a property is not defined in `myObject` use the property of `myDefaults`.
I mean, fill the blanks with the help of `myDefaults`.

I tried to use `$.extend`. But I encounter unexpected results. Now I am confused. Is it something that can not be done with  `$.extend`?

My Expected result is :

```
myObject = {
    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '12',
    color : '000000',
    weight : 'bold',
    decoration : 'underline'
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are not showing us how you tried to use it, and you aren't saying what the unexpected results are. We can't read your mind, and we can't help until we know.

Comment: I added my expected result instead of unexpecteds, sorry...

Comment: Guessing here, you most likely want `var result = $.extend({}, myDefaults, myObject)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) like

```
myDefaults = {
    fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '15',
    color: 'FF0000',
    weight: 'bold',
    decoration: 'underline'
}

myObject = {
    fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '12',
    color: '000000'
}

myObject = $.extend({}, myDefaults, myObject)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TeE5f/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your `single quote` after `underline` try this,

```
myDefaults = {
    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '15',
    color : 'FF0000',
    weight : 'bold',
    decoration : 'underline'
    //// you missed -------^
}
myObject = {
    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
    fontSize: '12',
    color : '000000'
}
myObject=$.extend({},myDefaults,myObject);
console.log(myObject);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2jEf/1/)

Comment: it will override all properties in `myObject` with that in defautls